# Getting survey URL as null in release mode in flutter error: java.lang.Exception: Cannot evaluate logic, no initialized intercept found

Tags: flutter, dart, hybrid-mobile-app, qualtrics

I am trying to implement the Qualtrics SDK in my flutter project and in the debug mode it's working fine but when I am trying to run the app in the release mode, it throwing error as:

**error: java.lang.Exception: Cannot evaluate logic, no initialized intercept found**

URL for the plugin:
[Qualtrics Digital Flutter Plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/qualtrics_digital_flutter_plugin)

Code Snippet:

```
Future<String> _initializeQualtrics() async {
String surveyUrl = '';
await qualtrics.initializeProject(brandId, projectId).then((value) 
 async {
  String result = "";
  var evaluateProjectResult = await qualtrics.evaluateProject();
  for (var interceptId in evaluateProjectResult.keys) {
    var targetingResult =
        evaluateProjectResult[interceptId].cast<String, String>();
    var passed = targetingResult["passed"];
    surveyUrl = targetingResult["surveyUrl"];
    result = '$result\n$interceptId: passed: $passed surveyUrl: $surveyUrl';
    print("surveyURL: $targetingResult");
  }
});
return surveyUrl;
```

}

```
 @override
 void initState() {
 super.initState();
 _initializeQualtrics().then((surveyUrl){
  if (surveyUrl != 'null' && surveyUrl != '') {
  showSurveyDialog(surveyUrl);
  }
  });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

After contacting Qualtrics support I find out that after adding these lines in my **android/app/build.gradle** the issue got fixed.

```
 buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        useProguard false
        shrinkResources false
    }
}
```